# Google app engine python logging not working

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I can't print to the browser console despite trying the code below.

```
import logging

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug("print this.")
```

Comment: logging.info('stuff') or logging.warning('badstuff') will work for you.

Comment: The exact same code printed for me.  How are you running this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the Python logging will get out to the browser console.

All the logs messages go out to the project dashboard (https://appengine.google.com/logs?&app_id=s~your-project), or to STDIO when developing locally.

If you want to see logging messages on the browser console, those have to be called by Javascript on the web page!